# How to fix warning after updating xcode 8.3 to 9.1

Tags: ios, xcode8, swift4, xcode9.1

I was working in Xcode 8.3 and developing a Ios project in swift 3. But since my iphone is not connecting to xcode so i updated the xcode to 9.1. Now there is lot of warning showing in my code.

e.g

> I was using SVProgresssHud but now its showing 3 warning and also
>   progress bar is not showing in simulator or  device, previously it was
>   showing.

Below image showing warnings:
[image]

I am using dependencies of facebook in that also warning is showing. I reinstall my all dependencies but it not solves. I don't have knowledge of objective c and I am very new to ios environment. 

Any help will always be appreciated.

Comment: Which iOS version do you target?

Comment: targeting 9.3 as it is necessary.